# How come widgets from ipywidgets is not defined in an html file?

Tags: python, html, jupyter-notebook, interactive

I am using nbinteract to develop an interactive web page from a Jupyter notebook. I finally got to the end and published the first version of it but it does not appear the python libraries loaded properly (see image below). This appears to be the problem even in the [original nbinteract tutorial](https://www.nbinteract.com/examples/examples_empirical_distributions.html). Any ideas on what might be the problem here?

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It’s possible to export a notebook including widgets to html using nbconvert (https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert ). You need to make sure to save the notebook using the classic Jupyter Notebook (not JupyterLab) with the “Widgets -> Save Notebook Widget State” menu option.

Unfortunately, it’s not possible to preserve the behavior of the callback functions this way because these functions are defined using Python, and there’s no Python kernel available in the standalone HTML file.

To host interactive figures outside of the notebook , writing a Dash app is always good (https://dash.plot.ly/ ). or If you want to stay in notebook/widget field you could use https://github.com/QuantStack/voila.

Comment: Interesting. May I ask then, why do the widgets work for some of the examples present in the nbinteract tutorial (https://www.nbinteract.com/tutorial/tutorial_interact.html)?

Comment: ipywidgets used is not a standalone HTML file so there is a python Kernel available that can process it

Comment: Ok interesting, this may be a foolish question but I am relatively new to github. How might I go about making the python kernel available to process it? What is the solution?